# OSM - Why source tag not exported?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I noticed that downloaded osm data do not have the source tag displayed in openstreetmap query:

For example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/95462202

[image]

Once extracted as .pbf or .bz2 from Geofabrik and converted to .osm, source tag is not in QGIS

[image]

It looks like a simple question but I am not too familiar with OSM data and workflows and I believe the source tag is helpful.

In addition to my question, I set the osmconf.ini file, actually to_be_modified_osmconf.ini file in the AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\QuickOSM\resources\ogr folder and nothing changed. It looks like QGIS is not using this file for environment parameters

[image]

And I have no clue where such environment parameters are found and used by QGIS

[image]

QGIS actually looks into C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.3\share\gdal for the osmconf.ini file. This is shown in Settings > Options > Current environment variables in GDAL_DATA variable. Strangely, Windows Explorer could not find the
osmconf.ini in this location!

[image]

It is all ok now and the 'source' tag is shown

[image]

Fantastic!

Just a little detail, how QGIS can deal with unicode characters not displaying correctly? Géodonnées - Etat de Vaud displays as GÃ©odonnÃ©es - Etat de Vaud

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GDAL OSM driver that is used for converting data from .pbf is documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html. The configuration file osmconf.ini controls which tags will be converted. You can find that file from your computer from gdal_data directory. The default osmconf.ini can also be found from GitHub https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/data/osmconf.ini.

You can see that some tags are intentionally ignored because they are considered to have less value than additional weight for average users.

```
# keys that should NOT be reported in the "other_tags" field
ignore=area,created_by,converted_by,source,time,ele,note,todo,openGeoDB:,fixme,FIXME
```

Edit your local osmconf.ini file and you will get the source tags. Notice that the setting is per layer and appears in 6 places in the osmconf.ini file.

Comment: I only found to_be_modified_osmconf.ini file in the AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\QuickOSM\resources\ogr folder.

I made the required changes to get the source tag but nothing changed. Is this file somewhere else? The osmconf.ini do not exist in my install... Although, imported tags from osm must find their parameters somewhere...

Comment: You should have GDAL installed as well. Does `SET GDAL_DATA` from your command line show anything?

Comment: You can also use QGIS Options-System-Current environmental variables for finding out the location of GDAL_DATA.

Comment: Thanks. In Command Line, Set GDAL_DATA is not recognized. As for QGIS Options-System-Current environmental variables, I put a screenshot above and I cannot find anything like osmconf.ini. Although, QGIS must look somewhere for these variables...

Comment: To be sure, the QGIS Current environmental variables does not have variable "GDAL_DATA" set? The screenshot is scrolled only to APPDATA.