# QGIS 3.24.1 - in QuickOSM, how to import raw OSM into GeoPackage and select which tags to import?

Tags: openstreetmap, null, quickosm, other-tags

With overpass-turbo, I made a query and exported a raw OSM file.

In QGIS 3.24.1, I import this OSM file into GeoPackage using the OSM File menu in QuickOSM plugin. It works but it imports all tags and most are NULL.

Is there any way to import a selection of tags and all the other non-NULL tags go to 'others tags'?

Is there any configuration file for importing raw OSM file into GeoPackage? Just as I did a while ago using osmconf.ini file with .pbf OSM - [Why source tag not exported?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432884/osm-why-source-tag-not-exported)

Comment: I noticed the OSMConf to use customized "osmconf.ini". I uncomment other_tags=yes and it works. 

# uncomment to avoid creation of "other_tags" field
other_tags=yes
# uncomment to create "all_tags" field. "all_tags" and "other_tags" are exclusive
#all_tags=yes

However, using this OSMConf option with customized the "osmconf.ini", I noticed that not all polygons are processed! In addition, instead of creating a GeoPackage, it only creates "in-memory" layers in QGIS. Is there any parameters in "osmconf.ini" file to force all polygons export (overlapping polygons in particular)?

Comment: To clarify my comment above. I noticed that using "osmconf.ini" creates in-memory layers which sometimes do not have all polygons OR with tags shifted! If exported to GeoPackage, this 'bug' persists! Closing and re-opening QGIS can solve the problem to display in-memory layers correctly. When displayed correctly in QGIS, exports to GeoPackages work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using QuickOSM with the "OSM file" menu, did you try other options in the dialog ? You can give the "osmconf.ini" using the third option.

You need to check the documentation on OGR about the OSMConf file https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html

The first option is giving all "tags" available in your dataset, so each column has at least one value in the column.

[image]